# How can we make the saveFrame() method in ExtractMpegFramesTest more efficient?

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

[edit] Reformatting into question and answer format following fadden@ suggestion.

In [ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt), method saveFrame(), there is a loop for reordering RGBA into ARGB for Bitmap png compression (see below quotes from that file), how can this be optimised?

```java
// glReadPixels gives us a ByteBuffer filled with what is essentially big-endian RGBA
// data (i.e. a byte of red, followed by a byte of green...).  We need an int[] filled
// with little-endian ARGB data to feed to Bitmap.
//
```

...

```java
// So... we set the ByteBuffer to little-endian, which should turn the bulk IntBuffer
// get() into a straight memcpy on most Android devices.  Our ints will hold ABGR data.
// Swapping B and R gives us ARGB.  We need about 30ms for the bulk get(), and another
// 270ms for the color swap.
```

...

```java
for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++) {
    int c = colors[i];
    colors[i] = (c & 0xff00ff00) | ((c & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) | ((c & 0x000000ff) << 16);
}
```

Comment: Good idea!  That swap loop is not especially fast in Java.

Comment: FWIW, I think the "official" way to offer suggestions would be to ask, "how can we make the saveFrame() method in ExtractMpegFramesTest more efficient?", and then answer your own question.  That way others are encouraged to present their own answers as well.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer .

Comment: Reformatted, thanks fadden!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out there's an even faster approach.

Using the suggestion in @elmiguelao's answer, I modified the fragment shader to do the pixel swap.  This allowed me to remove the swap code from saveFrame().  Since I no longer needed a temporary copy of the pixels in memory, I eliminated the `int[]` buffer entirely, switching from this:

```
int[] colors = [... copy from mPixelBuf, swap ...]
Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

to this:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(mPixelBuf);
```

As soon as I did that, all of my colors were wrong.

It turns out that `Bitmap#copyPixelsFromBuffer()` wants the pixels in RGBA order, *not* ARGB order.  The values coming out of `glReadPixels()` are already in the right format.  So by doing it this way I avoid the swap, avoid an unnecessary copy, and don't need to tweak the fragment shader at all.

Answer (score 3):

[edit] Reformatting into question and answer format following fadden@ suggestion

I wanted to suggest that this conversion can happen in the FragmentShader by changing the line

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
```

into

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord).argb;
```

which is an efficient shortcut to reorder in GPU the shader's output channels, that works in other ways too: `.abgr` or even `.bggr` etc.